# SO_RCVTIMEO socket option doesn't work with recvfrom()

Tags: c, network-programming

I set the socket option SO_RCVTIMEO  but really it doesn't work with UDP `recvfrom()` system call? Can anybody please help me?

Comment: You might paste your code so we can look for errors. Generally there shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

may be the timeout you are giving is too small and it is returning -1 with EAGAIN as errno.

Answer (score 0):

Possible error can be misusing select() function.
Don't forget to check its result for zero value.

The code should be like this:

```
int nRes = 0;

fd_set socketset;
memset(&socketset, 0, sizeof(socketset));
socketset.fd_count = 1;
socketset.fd_array[0] = sock;
timeval timeout = {0, 0};
timeout.tv_sec = dwTimeout / 1000;
timeout.tv_usec = (dwTimeout % 1000) * 1000;    // microseconds

nRes = select(0, &socketset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
if (nRes == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    return WSAGetLastError();
}
if (nRes == 0)  // timeout
{
    return WSAETIMEDOUT;
}

int nDestLen = sizeof(dest);
nRes = recvfrom (sock, (char*) &buf[0], buf.size(), 0,
    (sockaddr*) &dest, &nDestLen);
```